# is useful for a mathematician, at least for the learning of concepts, to expresss arguments in the language of logic?

Tags: logic, soft-question

I have a great interest in logic. So, I thought, Is possible to express all my arguments in logic?. Well, I know that in theory this is possible, so this would be the ideal of rigour, but in practice it doesn´t happen. A mathematician uses natural languages with the help of some signs. But I don't know why, I think that the possibility of expressing arguments will open the connection of conceptos. I don't know, what do you think?, is useful for a mathematician at least for the learning of concepts, to expresss arguments in the language of logic?, this is only with signs, without words.

Comment: Converting all mathematical arguments into the language of formal logic would, in my opinion, unnecessarily obfuscate your arguments, when appropriate rigour and clarity can be achieved using, as you put it, natural language.

Comment: Vocabulary of a natural language is imho is much larger than what  a repository of  symbolic logic can provide.

Comment: It can be useful when it comes to making proofs verifiable by software.

Comment: There would be a very large overhead of lemmas and definitions, and others might not be able to read your work. Still, I don't buy this weird aversion to logic. Reading an argument in natural/formal language is like reading it in English/Greek if you're comfortable enough, except if Greek was more precise than English. Thinking in terms of formal logic helps avoid false/incomplete proofs and misunderstandings.

Comment: I +1 the view that @ThomasAnton is presenting here. The achievement of formal logic is to give a very precise definition of what a proof is, and it is worth learning this. And you don't need to proof all of analysis in this way to learn it; No, very basic statements will suffice to teach the formal basics of proofs. And once you learned it you can return to natural language proofs - and from my experience - you will return with a new intuition of what a proof actually "is" and be much more confident in nailing down logical mistakes.